# Remove all database changes in a session

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I'm trying to create a fake login for a site. How I'm doing this is by hacking the login manager. How ever for this fake user, since this is a prod environment, I don't want him making any db changes but it would be really helpful if he can test the functionality properly.

So I was thinking maybe he can make all the changes he wants but they are removed as soon as he logs out. Yes I know transactions, but the thing is that transactions are being used already in the site, so what I want yo know is

Can I have a session wide transaction running which can be reverted when the session ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation : When he logs in, clone a database schema and use that schema. When logout / some time limit , remove the schema.